# Cannot use find-dired: setq: Searching for program: is a directory,

Tags: dired, shell, find-dired

The error is raised by `shell-command--shell-command-with-editor-mode`. But further stack trace is obfuscated by bytecompiled output. Recently I had to set

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "bash")
```

to be able to run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell` (it would give a similar error). I think this may be related, but I cannot find what exactly is broken.

This is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If you use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, trigger the problem again, and include the backtrace in your question, it might be easier for someone to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: You can also tell Emacs to `load` the uncompiled versions of the compiled libraries in question, which might (depending on what the compiled code is) help to produce a clearer backtrace.

Comment: @phils in this case it won't help because it `funcall`s the bytecompiled code, which it gets from elsewhere at runtime. I could probably track it down, but I was just hoping someone could recognize the symptoms without having to dive in. It's really odd that stock version of Emacs wouldn't work properly on a stock version of Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the problem: I also had to set `shell-file-name` to something other than `/bin/sh`, because Ubuntu ships with Dash as `sh` and Emacs relies on non-standard GNU features present in Bash, but not Dash.

Comment: Could you say which features those are? (and where is the Emacs code that uses them?)

Comment: @npostavs I found some reference to `$ESHEL` environment variable, but I stopped there, it's not the only one missing.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound like a bash feature...